# Java "Registering"(Storing) and removing "Employees"

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have a class called `Employee` and now I want to write a class called `ReusaxCorp`. Each employee at the company has an ID, a name and a gross salary, that can later be retrieved. The `ReusaxCorp` class should register and remove Employees (beginning with no employee). The problem I have is, that I don't know how I can register employees and store them. Furthermore, I was told to use polymorphism. Here's the Employee class:

```
public class Employee {

    private String ID;
    private String name;
    private int grosssalary; 

    public Employee (String ID, String name, int grosssalary){
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.grosssalary = grosssalary;
    }


    public int getGrosssalary() {
        return grosssalary;
    }

    public void setGrosssalary(int grosssalary) {
        this.grosssalary = grosssalary;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be homework

Comment: Homework questions are fine, but you have to show your attempt at a solution with your question. If you're completely lost, then you shouldn't be posting a question here -- you should be contacting your instructor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Griffin's answer has the elements to get you started. 
To elaborate on that, you should also make sure the Employee class overrides the methods equals() and hashCode() correctly, so you can safely use the List.remove(Object) method. 
For example, using the ID as key for unicity:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((ID == null) ? 0 : ID.hashCode());
    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
            return true;
    if (obj == null)
            return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (ID == null) {
            if (other.ID != null)
                    return false;
    } else if (!ID.equals(other.ID))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Now you can work around something like this in your ReusaxCorp class:

```
private List<Employee> mEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>()

/** 
 * Removes one employee from the corporation
 */
public void remove(Employee employee) {
    mEmployees.remove(employee);
}

/**
 * Inserts a new employee
 */
public void insert(Employee employee) {
    // can check for unicity (optional):
    if (mEmployees.contains(employee)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Employee already exists");

    mEmployees.add(employee);
}
```

If you only know the ID of the employee you want to remove, you can create a new Employee instance to match an existing one:

```
// Thanks to redefinition of equals(), it will match and remove the correct employee without having to know the name or salary.
corp.remove(new Employee(ID, "", 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad however Ill see if I can get you started...

You could go about 'registering' employees by utilizing an Array List of Employee objects.

```
//create array list
ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Now if you create an employee...

```
//create employee (of course enter whatever you need for your constructor)
Employee employee = new Employee("sampleID", "sampleName", 0);
```

You can add your employee to the array list. You can also remove elements from your array list at a specific index. Below are examples...

```
//add employee
employees.add(employee);
//remove employee(would have initialize int index to which you want to remove)
employees.remove(int index);
```

read up on array lists to see what else you can do with them. Im sure they have what you're looking for.